# Run command identifier RemoveFormat prior to running current command in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I have some custom style formats setup that will add a class to the selected text.  I have a request to clear the formatting/classes if user selects a new one.  They do not need multiple classes assigned.  Ideally I don't have to modify any core files for tinymce but willing to do so if necessary.

My thought process is to catch the selection of the formatting and then run RemoveFormat but it seems like it will run the initial command first.  It will format and then remove the formatting.  I am wondering if there is a way to hold the initial request and run RemoveFormat first and then set the new formatting.  Also if there is a better way to doing this I am open to that as well.  I am on version 4.7.

```
 ed.on('ExecCommand', function checkListNodes (evt) {
   let cmd = evt.command
   if (cmd === 'mceToggleFormat') {
      this.execCommand('RemoveFormat', false, '');
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution.  A bit hacky but gets the job done.  I set the variable before the tinymce init statement.  So it will run the formatting then clear all formatting for the selection and send over the option initially selected.  After clearing the formatting it will run the formatting again but this time not remove the formatting by checking for the variable that was switched to true.

```
let doNotRemoveFormat = false;

setup: function (ed) {
  ed.on('ExecCommand', function checkListNodes (evt) {
if (cmd === 'mceToggleFormat') {
    if(!doNotRemoveFormat) {  
      let val = 'runThis|' + evt.value;
      this.execCommand('RemoveFormat', false, val);
    } else {
      doNotRemoveFormat = false;
    }
} else if (cmd === 'RemoveFormat') {
  let value = evt.value.split("|");
  if(value[0] === 'runThis') {
    doNotRemoveFormat = true;
    this.execCommand('mceToggleFormat', false, value[1])
  }
});
```